# Convert a Number to a Sentence

Tags: number-theory

My task is to take any number, and have it replaced with a sentence/string representing its value. To be exact, I want something along the lines of;

- 150 = hi
- 151 = hj
- 152 = hk

This of course wouldn't use these values, but values that fit whatever equation solves my problem.

I do not want something along the lines of;

- 0809 = hi

where;

- 08 = h
- 09 = i

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking; of course you *can* do this, just by defining the correspondence in the way you already have. Are you asking how to implement this in a computer program, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the sentence represent a number in base $53$, for example by
$$\text{[space]}=0,\ \text a=1,\ \ldots,\ \text z=26,\ \text A=27,\ \ldots,\ \text Z=52.$$
Then
$$\text{hi}=8\times53+9=433.$$

This is invertible using division and remainders. For example, $3234$ is divisible by $53^2$ once, and gives the remainder $425$. The remainder $425$ is divisible by $53$ eight times, and gives the remainder $1$. Thus
$$3234=1\times53^2+8\times53+1=\text{aha}.$$